# Doxygen remove extra Index pages

Tags: latex, doxygen

The Doxygen LaTeX output starts with an extensive table of contents. Later on, it contains "Chapters" for the "Module Index," "File Index," etc. In my mind these Index chapters are totally redundant and I would like to get rid of them. How can I do so?

I also made a custom index-like `\page` for the HTML output, but would like to hide it from the LaTeX/PDF output. Is this possible?

Comment: Didi you have a look at \latexonly

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `\latexonly` and `\htmlonly` tags are used to include raw text to send directly to LaTeX or to HTML. So adding a `\htmlonly` tag around my index-like `\page` makes it disappear from both outputs.

Answer (score 0):

In your .in file, there are a bunch of settings for automatic file generation. All of these add-ons have a naming convention that follows the **GENERATE_XXXXX** format. Module Index can be turned off like so:

```
# The GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST tag can be used to enable (YES) or disable (NO)
# the deprecated list. This list is created by putting \deprecated commands in
# the documentation.
# The default value is: YES.

GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= NO
```

Comment: What does `GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST` (i.e. functions etc.that have been declared deprecated by e.g.`\deprecated`) have to do with modules?